# Effect of varying outcome duration in longitudinal studies

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, panel-data, model

I have a supervised classifier model (regularized discriminant) which predicts the probability of an event occurring within two years.

This model was developed using sensor data measured from a baseline assessment and followed up for the occurrence of an event **two years** later (outcome is a binary variable, '**Y**' or '**N**').

I wish to validate this method using a separate, independent test set. This independent test set contains the same baseline sensor data (measurements) but follow-up was recorded after **one year** (rather than two).

My question has two parts:

1. How should I excpect this shorter follow-up period to affect the models performance? (i.e. should I expect lower sensitivity for prediction of events, as events may not have happened **yet** within follow-up period)?
2. Is there a way to correct for this shorter outcome period (e.g. treat all outcome data as having equal hazard of 0.5 probability and therefore randomly label half of data points labelled '**Y**' as '**N**')?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume your events occurs in a poisson process, then the waiting time until an event is exponentially distributed with density function
$$
    f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \qquad \text{for}~~ y>0
$$
($\lambda>0$, the expectation of $Y$ is $1/\lambda$). Then the probability of an event in no more time than $a$ years is (a simple integral)
$P(Y \le a)=1-e^{-\lambda a}$. Calculate this with $a=1$ and then with $a=2$ and you get your correction factor.

You must of course think about IF this is a defensible assumption!